# How can i use filepond javascript library in Django template?

Tags: javascript, html, django, filepond

**Intro**: I have Django web app where users are allowed to create posts. Each post has multiple images that are associated with that post.

**What I want to do**: I want to use `Filepond` javascript library for remove, add more and previews of selected images.

**The issue**: The code below is working ok without filepond library but if i try to use filepond library the form is submitting only `title input` without files.

**views.py**

```
class NewsCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = FileForm
    template_name = 'create.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = self.request.user
        post.save()
        for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('filepond'):
            FileModel.objects.create(post=post, file=f)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**create.html**

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="hpanel" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="id_title" name="title" class="form-control">
                        <input type="file" id="id_file" name="file" multiple="true">                    
                    </div>
                    <button class=" btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.js"></script>

<script>
    FilePond.registerPlugin(
        FilePondPluginImagePreview
    );

    FilePond.create(
        document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to set a file input value, see: https://pqina.nl/blog/the-trouble-with-editing-and-uploading-files-in-the-browser/

So FilePond won't update the existing file input.

You either have to upload the file asynchronously by setting the FilePond `server` property or use the Filepond File Encode plugin to encode the file as base64 data which can be sent to the server as a string.